# Why if I don't malloc() some memory, use char * will cause program to stop?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I recently faced a bug, which I figure out why. The situation is that I use char `*arr`, then something like `scanf("%s",arr);`. My program stopped unexpectedly which later I figure out it's because I forgot to use malloc() to allocate a specified area of memory. However, I'm still wondering why this can happen(memory leak?)! I don't actually do anything that actually modify the memory other than the first scanf that initialize the string. 
an example is like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int *narr;
    int *count;
    int i,j,k;
    char *temp=malloc(sizeof(char)*101);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    narr=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    count=malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        count[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %s",narr+i,temp);
        k=narr[i];
        count[k]++;
    }
    for(i=0,k=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        k+=count[i];
        printf("%d ",k);
    }
    return 0;
```

If I don't use malloc, then OJ will face error.

Comment: What do you think *should* happen in this case?

Comment: You are poking garbage in random memory. 
Imagine that you are changing call stack, program counter, memory mapped IO.

Comment: It will not "cause the program to stop" (there is a function to do this: `exit`). Writing to random memory will invoke Undefined Behavior, which is something else.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I realized that everything I do after the pointer may actually ruin the memory. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers have to point to something, no?  When you declare:

```
char *temp=malloc(sizeof(char)*101);
```

Then you have instructed the C runtime library to grab chunk of memory from the OS and return it to you for your use.  If you just declared:

```
 char *temp;
```

you now have an initialized pointer, that is most likely pointing to who-knows-what.  If you then try to stuff data in there, the behavior is undefined. I would suggest reading up on [Pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html) and memory management in C.

Comment: `malloc()` returns a *poniter to the memory*, not the memory itself [/nitpick]